# Reformating query parameters in the route

Tags: ember.js

I have a controller query parameter:

```
export default Controller.extend({
    myParam: undefined,
    queryParams: ['myParam'],
});
```

that I want to refresh the model with:

```
export default Route.extend({
    queryParams: {
        myParam: {
            refreshModel: true
        }
    }
});
```

This correctly formats and tracks the variable in my app's URL (in other words the browser URL):

```
myapp.com?myParam=1
```

and correctly sends the corresponding request to my API:

```
[GET] myapi.com?myParam=1
```

I want to remap the query parameter so that I can continue to use the  `myParam` variable in my controller, but the request to my *API* gets mapped to:

```
[GET] myapi.com?my_param=1
```

I've tried the following on my *controller*:

```
export default Controller.extend({
    queryParams: {
        myParam: 'my_param'
    },
});
```

and this makes the URL in my application (the browser URL) correctly change to `my_param` when I change the variable:

```
myapp.com?my_param=1
```

but it *doesn't* change the parameter that is sent to my *API*, which remains:

```
[GET] myapi.com?myParam=1
```

Is there away to map the variable that is refreshing the model in my route to a different URl param?

**EDIT**

I've noticed that the route `queryParams` variable can have an `as` attribute:

```
export default Route.extend({
    queryParams: {
        myParam: {
            refreshModel: true,
            as: 'my_param'
        }
    }
});
```

but setting that seems to just have the same effect - it changes the *app* URL but not the *api* URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the quick & dirty solution is to add this to the route:

```
model(params) {
    if ('myParam' in params) {
      params['my_param'] = params['myParam'];
      delete params['myParam'];
    }
    return this._super(...arguments);
}
```

There must be a cleaner way of doing this though.

Is there any built-in way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Usually I do it like this:

```
//controller
import { alias } from '@ember/object/computed';

....

queryParams: ['my_param'],
myParam: alias('my_param')

//route 

model({ my_param }) {

}
```

then you can use `myParam` in your templates. URL and `model` callback will use `my_param`.